# Are comments in spanish accepted?

Tags: discusión, comentarios

I think that comments in Spanish should be accepted. I've been having a series of flags condemning comments in Spanish for some reason. For now I've been dismissing them but for the sake of having a meta precedent I'm writing this question.

I think we agree that comments in Spanish are accepted? (maybe I'm wrong, you, the community decide.) So cast your votes or answer what you think, there are no wrong answers!

Comment: So the flag as "in need of moderator attention" and as a reason they just state "it is written in Spanish"? I don't know if moderator tools show this, but, do they come always from a single user or from multiple?

Comment: @Diego Yes the mod tools show the reasons. You have the option to flag something as "other" and give a comment about why you flagged it. Some flags just say "it is written in another language" namely spanish in those cases.

Comment: Comments in Spanish should definitely be accepted.  Even the flags for moderator attention should be processed by software that is aware of the fact that this site is about Spanish.  It may be hard to get there from here.

Answer (score 9):

Our [official policy](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is that **Spanish is preferred**:

> #### Should I post in Spanish or English?
>
> Spanish is preferred, although both languages are accepted. If you are learning Spanish, we suggest that you learn by doing, and ask in Spanish, but there is no obligation. Posts made in English will likely be translated to Spanish for you. When answering a question, we encourage you to answer in the language of the question, if you are able. Don't worry about making a few mistakes, other community members can help with corrections if you are not as strong in that language.

This applies to questions, answers, and comments. The only place where English is preferred (and, indeed, required) is here on meta. (Spanish is OK on meta, as long as an English translation is also provided).

As a matter of courtesy to the OP, our policy also states that we encourage answering (and this ought to apply to comments, as well) in the language of the OP, but this is not required, either.

So anyone raising flags about comments being in Spanish is wrong, according to our long-standing policy.  Hopefully whoever is raising these flags will be inclined to comment here if they hope to affect a change in this policy.

Comment: Didn't know it also applied for comments, as the text cited doesn't specify that. It would be a useful, if precise, addition.

Comment: I suppose there's a little room for interpretation, but it does talk about posting in general, then only later specifically mentions questions and answers.  We could add comments, too, if we think it's useful.

Answer (score 8):

**ESPAÑOL (English follows)**

Yo creo que todos los aportes, (preguntas, respuestas y comentarios) deberían admitirse en español y/o inglés.

En el caso de una pregunta o una respuesta, siempre se puede editar para agregar una traducción. En el caso de un comentario no es posible editarlo para traducirlo, pero los comentarios que aporten valor a una pregunta o a una respuesta podrían ser incluidos en dicha pregunta o respuesta, usando ambos idiomas si es conveniente.

---

**ENGLISH**

I think all contributions (questions, answers and comments) should be allowed in spanish and/or english.

In the case of a question or an answer, you can always edit it to add a translation. In the case of a comment you can not edit to translate it, but the comments that add value to a question or to an answer could be included in such question or answer, using both languages if appropriate.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a good compromise.

Answer (score 2):

### Español:

Soy nuevo, pero creo que las preguntas que hagan estarían mucho mejor sí las hacen en español, ya que así llega a más gente, como a mi por ejemplo, que no entiendo ingles del todo.

En el caso de una respuesta, entiendo que los que preguntan, la prefieran a la respuesta en su idioma natal, en esté caso, yo me esfuerzo un poco en intentar traducir como puedo, pero dudo que lo haga de forma certera.

=========================================================================

### English:

I'm new, but I think their questions are much better if you do them in Spanish, as this reaches more people, like me for example, I don't understand English at all.

For an answer, I understand that those wondering, the prefer to answer in their native language, in this case, I struggle a bit in trying to translate as, but I doubt they do so accurate.